# Automatic link-to-title conversion in migrated posts

Tags: bug, migration, hyperlinks

I posted [an answer to a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16369276/914686) that was [migrated to TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112320/5764). My original answer included a destination URL on TeX.SE and was therefore not automatically converted to it's title equivalent. However, now that the post has been migrated, the automatic conversion has still not taken place.

Interestingly, editing the post reveals an updated, converted title-form of the URL. Migrated post (now on TeX.SE):

> [image]

Rendered post during an edit:

> [image]

Is there a way to have these URLs automatically update across networks? Or, upon conversion (without a visible alternative/source), be updated?