# Tags are still rendered as sponsored tags after migration

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, migration

I noticed this on this question: [Get full list of Autocomplete entries?](https://superuser.com/questions/565763/get-full-list-of-autocomplete-entries)

[image]

The [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) in the body text has the Google Chrome logo in it, while the tag itself on the question doesn't.

The tag isn't sponsored on Super User. I'm assuming it is somehow related to the question being migrated from Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'll bet that editing the question will remove the logo.

Comment: When did that start happening? I didn't think sponsorships got rendered in the post itself... I guess people using tags in the actual post on SO just happens so infrequently. :/

Comment: @animuson: I'm seeing it for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We "bake" markdown upon edit and store it in the question record for caching purposes. In particular, the way a tag is rendered is different on Stack Overflow because of tag sponsorship.

However, re-baking questions upon migration seems... unnecessarily complicated as validation rules differ slightly across sites.

If the community feels the tag should be unsponsored, a small edit will revert the tag to the correct rendering.

Comment: Rebaking the question could address the lack of beautification of links upon migration too - [Automatic link-to-title conversion in migrated posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184734/automatic-link-to-title-conversion-in-migrated-posts) and [Link to title beautifier not engaged upon migration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201657/link-to-title-beautifier-not-engaged-upon-migration)

Comment: Another issue I just encountered: when posts using `[tag:something]` on Meta Stack Exchange get migrated to Meta Stack Overflow, they actually link to `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/something` instead of `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/something`, i.e. the meta tag rather than the main tag. Example: first revision of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385511/4642212).