# Link to title beautifier not engaged upon migration

Tags: bug, migration, hyperlinks

If you give the raw link to a question on a site or its meta - for example the raw text of `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts` becomes [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) on MSO without need for `[]()` or `[][1]` style linkage.

If a question from another site (lets say Programmers.SE) has such a bare link to another site (lets say Stack Overflow) and is migrated to Stack Overflow, the automatic title beautifier is not engaged in the contents of the question or the answer leaving the raw link in place.

It appears that editing the question or answer in any way will cause the title beautifier to be engaged on the post in question *and its history* (so I don't have a good example at the moment).

Comment: (and yea... after posting and browsing the related questions, found an earlier post that pointed out the same issue in an SO to TeX migration) - though it was never answered there and is still an open issue.

Comment: That does not mean that it is not a duplicate

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA it certainly is a duplicate (note the first close vote cast) - just that it didn't show up in the set of similar questions *with answers* that appear when you are entering a question.  And on the related questions, its the very last one.  Just explaining why I didn't see it when I wrote the question.

Comment: Ahhh ok then ^_^ Got it